# Compiling with Boost using Clang errors

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python, clang++

I've been trying to compile a library (caffe) with the boost library using clang as the compiler on OSX 10.9. I'm running into a lot of errors with boost (version 1.57). Any suggestions on how to proceed? Here are what the errors look like. They're mostly about the same two issues below.

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread.hpp:13:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread_only.hpp:17:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:11:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/lock_guard.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/move.hpp:27:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/move/utility.hpp:21:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/move/traits.hpp:20:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/is_nothrow_move_assignable.hpp:15:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/has_trivial_move_assign.hpp:16:
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/is_const.hpp:57:105: error: 'T' does not refer to a value
   BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(bool, value = ::boost::detail::cv_traits_imp<BOOST_TT_AUX_CV_TRAITS_IMPL_PARAM(T)>::is_const);
                                                                                                        ^
/usr/local/include/boost/config/suffix.hpp:394:72: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT'
#     define BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(type, assignment) static const type assignment
                                                                       ^
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/is_const.hpp:51:17: note: declared here
template <class T>


usr/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_day.hpp:44:45: error: type 'greg_day_rep' (aka 'constrained_value<greg_day_policies>') is not a direct or virtual base of 'boost::gregorian::greg_day'
    greg_day(unsigned short day_of_month) : greg_day_rep(day_of_month) {}
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_day.hpp:45:46: error: use of undeclared identifier 'value_'
    unsigned short as_number() const {return value_;}
                                             ^
/usr/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_day.hpp:46:46: error: use of undeclared identifier 'value_'
    operator unsigned short()  const {return value_;}
```

Comment: Use of undeclared identifier is, as suggested, due to an undeclared identifier (variable). This could happen because you forgot to declare it, or misspelt it. However, as this occured in a library, this is not the case. Most likely, you either have not included all the necessary files to compile the library, or a linking error. Check your compilation routine.